# What is the use of operator !! in C?

Tags: c, pointers, operators

Hi everyone I am sending to you my piece of code. 
I think to answer my question this code is enough so I didn't send all of code.
In switch case I can see T1,T2 using with double ! what does that mean?

```
BinQueue
    Merge( BinQueue H1, BinQueue H2 )
    {
        BinTree T1, T2, Carry = NULL;
        int i, j;

        if( H1->CurrentSize + H2->CurrentSize > Capacity )
            Error( "Merge would exceed capacity" );

        H1->CurrentSize += H2->CurrentSize;
        for( i = 0, j = 1; j <= H1->CurrentSize; i++, j *= 2 )
        {
            T1 = H1->TheTrees[ i ]; T2 = H2->TheTrees[ i ];

            switch( !!T1 + 2 * !!T2 + 4 * !!Carry )//what does mean??
            {
                case 0: /* No trees */
                case 1: /* Only H1 */
                    break;
                case 2: /* Only H2 */
                    H1->TheTrees[ i ] = T2;
                    H2->TheTrees[ i ] = NULL;
                    break;
                case 4: /* Only Carry */
                    H1->TheTrees[ i ] = Carry;
                    Carry = NULL;
                    break;
                case 3: /* H1 and H2 */
                    Carry = CombineTrees( T1, T2 );
                    H1->TheTrees[ i ] = H2->TheTrees[ i ] = NULL;
                    break;
                case 5: /* H1 and Carry */
                    Carry = CombineTrees( T1, Carry );
                    H1->TheTrees[ i ] = NULL;
                    break;
                case 6: /* H2 and Carry */
                    Carry = CombineTrees( T2, Carry );
                    H2->TheTrees[ i ] = NULL;
                    break;
                case 7: /* All three */
                    H1->TheTrees[ i ] = Carry;
                    Carry = CombineTrees( T1, T2 );
                    H2->TheTrees[ i ] = NULL;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return H1;
    }
```

Comment: Give your question a more better title?

Answer (score 5):

`!` means logical `NOT`. `!!` means `NOT NOT`.

Logical `NOT` is 1 if the operand is zero, and 0 otherwise.
`!!` is 1 if the operand is non-zero, and 0 if the operand is zero.

It's a convenient way to map the operand into binary (0, 1) scale.

You can rewrite `!!p` as `(p ? 1 : 0)`.

In your case, `!!p` is zero if `p` is NULL, and `1` if `p` is non-NULL.

Answer (score 3):

! is logical NOT. `!x` is 1 if `x` is 0, or 0 if `x` is not 0.

`!!x` is 1 if `!x` is 0, or 0 if `!x` is not 0.

So `!!x` is 0 if `x` is 0, or 1 if `x` is not 0.

Short version: it converts all non-zero values to 1.

Answer (score 2):

!! means not(not(integer)). A way to turn integers to boolean (true/false).

Example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = !!a; // b = 1
```

Comment: This is C, not C++, so it turns integers into 0 or 1 *only*.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is an unary operator for "logical not", returning 1 (true) if the value is 0, or 0 (false) otherwise.

The same effect can be created using a comparison (`a == 0`) or the ternary operator (`a ? 0 : 1`).

By performing the operation twice, you'll get one more negation, so the final result for `!!a` would be `(a == 0) == 0` or shorter: `a != 0` (`a ? 1 : 0`).

The resulting code should (depending on your compiler) always be the same, but `!a` or `!!a` is just a lot shorter and easier to read, especially in longer expressions.

Used with pointers this essentially creates a simple check "is not a NULL pointer". For a simple `if()` this is not needed (due to implicit conversion to a boolean value), but you'll need it if you'd like to put the value/result into a bit field (as in this case).

---

Let's look at the switch statement:

```
switch( !!T1 + 2 * !!T2 + 4 * !!Carry )
```

What's happening here is essentially the creation of a bit field. The addition/multiplication is used to shift the bits and merge the result.

The bits from right to left:

- `!!T1`: The first bit is set if `T1` is not 0 (i.e. not `NULL`).
- `2 * !!T2`: The second bit is set if `T2` is not 0.
- `4 * !!Carry`: The third bit is set if `Carry` is not 0.

The actual cases for the `switch()` then just represent these bit fields and are used for comparison to determine the proper code for the different cases.